# MSFlow - "Add Dynamic content" option missing from "Compose" action

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, flow

All the examples of the `Compose` action on the web seem to show it having the `Add dynamic content` option below the text box. I do not see this link - what could cause this?

I'm attempting to compose a Date based on today's date, using a function, but without the dynamic content dialog I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a browser-related issue. Take a reference to this article: [Add dynamic content is missing in Flows](https://sharepointconnectblog.wordpress.com/2018/12/17/add-dynamic-content-is-missing-in-flows/). Also, you can change a browser to have a try.

Comment: I was deeply sceptical about this, as I am using the latest Edge. Tried it in Chrome as well - still didn't work (although that's Chromium too, so not surprising). Tried Firefox and boom, there it is!
So the moral of the story is don't use Microsoft's browser to access Microsoft's products.